# How to change divider color in iOS for UISplitView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to change the color of the divider? If so, how?

I've researched as much as possible here and on Google, without luck. I'm surprised it isn't more common...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the detailViewController of the SplitViewController, I added the following code to cover up the black line. My custom header is blue and 88px tall.

```
//blue line that covers the vertical black separator in the header
UIView *blueHeaderSplitViewSeparatorMask = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 2, 88)];
[blueHeaderSplitViewSeparatorMask setBounds:CGRectMake(320, 0, 2, 88)];
[blueHeaderSplitViewSeparatorMask setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:96.0f/255.0f blue:182.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
[self.view.superview addSubview:blueHeaderSplitViewSeparatorMask];
```

Answer (score 20):

On iOS 7, the fix is to set the background color of your UISplitViewController to the same as the deep background color (probably black).

Comment: It works with iOS 6 too. [self.splitViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: iOS8 & Swift too: `self.splitViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()`

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle the status bar. The divider is black everywhere else except for that 20px at the top.

Answer (score 12):

There is a quicker and better way of doing it. Just change spliViewController's view backgroundColor property:

```
    splitViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean the one-point line between the left and right view controllers? No, UISplitViewController doesn’t expose a way to change that. You might try creating an opaque view with the same size as the split view controller’s view and its `backgroundColor` set to the color you want, then add it below the other two controllers’ views like this:

```
splitController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftController, rightController, nil];
[splitController.view insertSubview:theBackgroundView atIndex:0];
```